# Why isn't a cron job running in a personally modified CentOS docker image?

Tags: docker, cron, docker-image

I am trying to make a docker image using a CentOS 7 base image of a private registry.

A cron operation is needed, so I first tested with printing 'hello cron' with a public CentOS 7 image.

My Dockerfile using a public Centos 7 image:

```
FROM centos:7.4.1708

RUN localedef -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 && \
        yum update -y

RUN yum install -y python3 cronie vim && \
        pip3 install requests

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD ["crond", "-n"]
```

In this case, it seems to work properly.

```
[root@091c362de99c app]# cat /var/log/cron.log
hello cron
hello cron
hello cron
```

So, I tried the same way using a personal CentOS 7 base image.
My Dockerfile using a private image:

```
FROM base.REGISTRY/centos7/jdk:8.x64

RUN localedef -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 && \
        yum update -y

RUN yum install -y python3 cronie vim && \
        pip3 install requests

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

CMD ["crond", "-n"]
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

```
[root@31580092ecec app]# cat /var/log/cron.log
cat: /var/log/cron.log: No such file or directory
```

---

Commands done with a public image:

```
[root@091c362de99c app]# crontab -l
* * * * * python3 /app/hello.py >> /var/log/cron.log
[root@091c362de99c app]# cat /app/hello.py
print('hello cron')
[root@091c362de99c app]# cat /var/log/cron.log
hello cron
hello cron
hello cron
hello cron
hello cron
```

Commands done with a private image:

```
[root@31580092ecec app]# crontab -l
* * * * * python3 /app/hello.py >> /var/log/cron.log
[root@31580092ecec app]# cat /app/hello.py
print('hello cron')
[root@31580092ecec app]# cat /var/log/cron.log
cat: /var/log/cron.log: No such file or directory
```

I want to figure out the differences between the two, but what I can do was just checking `crontab -l`.

Other than a cron job, just running a python file once works well with the both Dockerfile.
`CMD ["python", "./hello.py"]`

What could be a way to find out the differences to solve this problem?

Comment: What does `ls -lah /var` return on both containers?

Comment: @IonutTicus That command returns the same results. 
adm, cache, db, empty, games, gopher, kerberos, lib, local, lock, log, mail, nis, opt, preserve, run, spool, tmp, yp

Comment: Do you get any error message if you try to log into the bad container and manually run `crond`?

Comment: @IonutTicus Does "manually run crond" mean `crond -n` command? When `crond -n` is entered, no output is seen for both containers. When I ctrl-c after a few minutes, a log is generated for the normal container, but not for the bad container.